# How to create widget for my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, widget

Widgets are one of the interesting features in `iOS5`. But there are only Weather and Stocks widgets at this moment. So, is there any way to create widget for my app and show the dynamic content in it(hot news, for example)?

Documentation doesn't contain any info about this one. Only for `Dashboard Widget Tutorial` but it's for Mac and from 2009. Maybe this functionality is hidden, and there is a some private API?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you got answer to your question please to post how to use ios facebook comment widget in our app?

Answer (score 4):

There is no public API for widgets at the moment. I'd imagine this will be apart of the SDK at some point, maybe 5.1 or 5.2. For now, I believe you have to jailbreak your iDevice in 5.0. The jailbreak community has lots of tutorials on how to create widgets when jailbroken.

Comment: Yeah it's a real pity this isn't available already.  Would be cool to have your own app pushing messages to the notifications area.

Comment: You app's push notifications do show up in Notification Center, but they can be turned off by the user. I do think widgets will be added to a future version of iOS though, it just makes sense.