# Is it possible to create a widget for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, widget

I'm a little bit confused now. There is a weather and stock widget on the iPhone. Is it possible to create such a widget yourself? I don't want to talk about new features in iOS 5 here. I only want to know it in general (iOS < 5).

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html) I found the introduction guide with the help of Dashcode.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashboard_%28Mac_OS%29) also states that this is not possible. I always thought it would be.

So are there only web apps and native apps possible?

PS: What is a widget exactly? A combination of native app and HTML, CSS, Javascript? Only HTML, CSS, Javascript? A cocoa application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create widget for my iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767906/how-to-create-widget-for-my-ios-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html) isn't a Guide for iOS Widgets, it's Guide for Mac Dashboard Widgets.

You **can't**

- create iOS Widgets
- change how the iOS Notifications Appear

With Dashcode you can create Web Applications for both iOS and Mac. It's a combination of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Those Web Applications are only available on the Web (e.g. Safari). If you wan't to create a native App you have two possibilities:

1. Create a real native Application in ObjC
2. Create a Web Application (e.g. with Dashcode) and load it into a UIWebView, this requires also ObjC.

---

### Advantages

**Web-only Application (Browser-App)**

- You don't need a Apple Developer Account
- Easy to port to Mac and other Smartphones

**Unreal-native Application (Browser-App in a native App)**

- Easy to port to other Smartphones
- It feels like a real native app
- Your app is on the App Store

**Native Application (Real iOS-App)**

- You have **full** access to the iPhone Frameworks (e.g. Contacts.app)
- Your app is on the App Store

### Disadvantages

**Web-only Application (Browser-App)**

- The user needs to know your URL
- You're **not** in the App Store

**Unreal-native Application (Browser-App in a native App)**

- You need to pay 99$/year for an Apple Developer Account
- It *could* feel like it's not a native app
- You have not the full access to the iPhone Frameworks except you use something like ***PhoneGap*** or ObjC

**Native Application (Real iOS-App)**

- You need to pay 99$/year for an Apple Developer Account
- You can't port your app easy to other Smartphone
- You need to learn ObjC

Answer (score 3):

No, iOS does not currently allow the creation of widgets. The weather and stock widgets you're talking about were created by Apple. There are no APIs to write your own.

Comment: Apple calls its Weather and Stocks apps "widgets" but in reality they're normal iOS applications (though their UIs may be implemented within a `UIWebView`.)

Comment: And the `UIWebView` accesses data from a server with the help of HTML, CSS and Javascript?

Comment: I think they're native apps, not simple web views. When Apple say widget I think they just mean "simple app," kind of analagous to Dashboard widgets in Mac OS X, though there's no technical similarity.

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS8, its possible. 3rd party apps will be able to create widgets for the notification center.

http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2014/06/02Apple-Releases-iOS-8-SDK-With-Over-4-000-New-APIs.html

Comment: Can we create iTunes playlist widget in iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

No, currently thats not possible. But you can, and should, file a feature request at bugreport.apple.com so that this issue gets some attention.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you can't create a widget like component using javascript and display it in a uiwebview. This works equally well in android and iOS

A few years ago when I was involved with java server pages development I put together a tutorial of using dashcode to wrap java or javascript components.

http://www.jsfcentral.com/listings/A21034;jsessionid=A15086803ABF96A63DB1AB5405C9A329?link